# How do I run this flask application without getting this error message?

Tags: python, flask

```
(venv) -MBP microblog % flask run
 * Serving Flask app "microblog.py"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

Error: While importing "microblog", an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users//microblog/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/Users//microblog/microblog.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import app
ImportError: cannot import name 'app' from 'app' (unknown location)
```

I have tried `export FLASK_APP=microblog.py`

I have also tried to run it from multipled directories I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

Thanks.

Comment: first edit question and use special function to format it.

Comment: you use `from app import app` - do you have file `app.py` ? It doesn't have problem with `microblog.py` but it can't find `app.py`

Comment: I have app as a directory

Comment: do you have `app/__init__.py` with `app = Flask()` ? You can use `os.getcwd()` to see `Current Working Directory` - maybe it searchs it in different folder.

Comment: Yea I have it set to app = Flask(__name__)